# Not able to send mail from localhost through yahoo,gmail smtp server

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp, gmail, smtpclient

What is wrong in below mentioned asp.net code while sending test mail from my localhost web application?

> Error: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was
>   not authenticated.  The server response was: 5.7.1 Authentication
>   required

```
        string smtpAddress = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
        int portNumber = 587;
        bool enableSSL = true;

        string emailFrom = "abcdefg@gmail.com";
        string password = "12345";
        string emailTo = "zyxw@gmail.com";
        string subject = "Hello";
        string body = "Hello, I'm just writing this to say Hi!";

        using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
        {
            mail.From = new MailAddress(emailFrom);
            mail.To.Add(emailTo);
            mail.Subject = subject;
            mail.Body = body;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            // Can set to false, if you are sending pure text.


            using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(smtpAddress, portNumber))
            {
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false; 
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emailFrom, password);
                smtp.EnableSsl = enableSSL;
                smtp.Send(mail);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

The server requires an authentication. Yahoo doesn't just send emails for anybody. I don't think you can send an email through their gateway using a Google account.

Comment: ya thanks. it worked. is there any other way to send mail without gmail or yahoo authentication?

Comment: You can set up your own SMTP server or there are a huge number of mail services available across the web.  Most all of them require an account/subscription/authentication of some sort.